# SQLite database where two tables refer to each other alternative

Tags: sql, database, sqlite

I want to have a database with two tables, like so:

```
Parent
-------
Pk
UgliestChildPk
StrongestChildPk


Child
------
Pk
ParentPk
```

I'm working with SQLite, although that probably doesn't pertain much.
In my model, a Parent always has at least one Child, in which case the ugliest one and the strongest one would be the Parent's only Child.
I need to be able to retrieve all of a Parent's Children (via the Child.ParentPk foreign key). I also need to be able to efficiently retrieve a Parent's ugliest and strongest child.
I need to be able to add and remove children, as well as change which ones are the ugliest and strongest.

I gather it throws a flag that the Parent and Child tables both refer to each other. Is there a better way to accomplish these sorts of relationships?

I could add an IsUgliest and IsStrongest column to the Child table, but I want to efficiently ensure that there is one and only one ugliest and strongest child for each Parent (although they could be the same).
I also don't want to have to add indexes to the IsUgliest and IsStrongest columns in order to retrive them quickly. The schema I've described prevents that since the Pk columns are implicitly indexed anyway.

Is there a better way?
Any suggestions?

Comment: If you want to ensure that there are not any "average" children (not strongest and not ugliest), you will have to do a check when you are replacing them. What I mean is: I want to replace the strongest child of parent X. Is the "old" child strongest/ugliest for anyone else? If it is not, you can remove it and insert the new child. If the old child "still has its use" (it is the strongest/ugliest child for the same or another parent) you just update the parent but do not delete the child. Or using another approach you could do an update of parent and remove all "useless" children afterwards.

Comment: Your proposed schema is fine.  Why do you say "I gather it throws a flag that the Parent and Child tables both refer to each other"?

Comment: People seem to frown on such structures, partly I think because it creates an impossible chicken/egg situation when trying to use foreign key constraints.

Comment: I like this table design. All columns should be not nullable (every parent has a child, every parent has a strongest child, every parent has an ugliest child, every child has a parent), and the foreign key constraints would have to be deferred (https://sqlite.org/foreignkeys.html#fk_deferred). That should work in my opinion.

Comment: I forgot about the deferred foreign key constraints, that's helpful!

Answer (score 0):

I prefer option 2 below as it would be the easiest to maintain and craft logic for.

**Option 1**

One way to accomplish this would be to specify the `[strongest] not null unique` in the table creation. You would then decide how you wanted to list the strongest, e.g. 1 being the strongest.

Although this would allow you to do what you are asking, you would need some logic to rearrange the values in the table so that you could add or remove other children. This would allow you to easily reassign the ugliest child based on the ascending/descending order you set on your ugly/strength score

**Option 2**

A second way to do this would be to still use the IsStrongest and IsUgliest columns, but set their type to Boolean, and then perform a check to make sure there is only one person set to `true` when attempting to add a new ugliest or strongest child.

**Option 3**
Use the table structure you provided to quickly keep track of the strongest and ugliest child right in the parent table. You would probably need an alternate way of tracking the strength and beauty of a child so that you can easily determine who is the parent's ugliest/strongest child

**Additionally**
If you have the possibility of having more than one parent, you should use a linked table that looks like this

```
Parent_Child
------------
PCPK
Parent_FK
Child_FK
```